# Searching a list of strings

Tags: linux

I have values in file A like

```
301310
304790
500011
600462
607348
614269
```

I want to search all these values in a text file B which has lines like this

```
1.35|10|5|11|1p36.31|GPR153|P|G protein-coupled receptor 153||614269|REc|||| | |4(Gpr153)|
1.36|3|24|06|1p36.31|HES2|P|Hairy/enhancer of split, Drosophila, homolog of, 2||609970|REc|||| | ||
1.37|3|24|06|1p36.31|HES3|P|Hairy/enhancer of split, Drosophila, homolog of, 3||609971|REc|||| | ||
1.38|3|24|06|1p36.33|HES4|P|Hairy/enhancer of split, Drosophila, homolog of, 4||608060|REc|||| | ||
1.39|3|24|06|1p36.32|HES5|P|Hairy/enhancer of split, Drosophila, homolog of, 5||607348|REc|||| | ||
```

I want to print all lines which contain any of the term from file A and print them in an output file.

I tried following command but it is not working

```
grep -w -F -f fileA fileB >file C
```

Comment: Your example works ok for me. (Once I put one of the values from fileA in fileB, that is.)

Comment: grep -w -F -f fileA fileB >file C

Comment: Note: I edited your question for highlighting -- if your fileA actually has those empty lines between each number, you'll want to delete those, else you'll get a match on every line of fileB.

Comment: How is it failing? Is it showing lines it shouldn't, or not showing lines that it should?

Comment: BTW, there shouldn't be a space between `file` and `C`. Is that just a copying error?

Comment: it is showing lines it shouldn't. I am using command like this                  grep -w -F -f fileA fileB >fileC

Comment: Make sure there are no blank lines in fileA.

Comment: Oh..There was a blank line in file A now it nicely work. Thank you so very much Alex.

Comment: @AlexHowansky Post that as an answer, and explain why it solves the problem.

Comment: Done. @IshtiaqAhmad  please accept my answer if it worked ok for you.

Comment: You can even trim the options to `grep -f fileA fileB > fileC`. The pattern is already a fixed field, no need for `-F`, and `-w` word regex makes no difference here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you posted your question, you had your fileA like this:

```
301310

304790

500011
```

I edited the post for formatting, and removed the empty lines figuring it was just a editing typo on your part. If your input file actually *does* have empty lines in it, you'll want to remove them, as grep will interpret them as "match an empty pattern", which matches every line. It would equate to:

```
grep "" fileB
```

So, just wipe the empty lines from fileA and your posted grep command should work just fine.

Comment: Yes, I removed empty lines and it worked. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

If you're grep isn't working then maybe a perlish solution? 
Although I will point out - given your data examples, no matches are found, which could be part of the problem.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
open ( my $file1, '<', "FileA" ) or die $!; 

my @search_for = <$file1>; 
close ( $file1 );

my $search_regex = join ( "|", map {quotemeta} @search_for ); 
   $search_regex = qr/$search_regex/; 

open ( my $file2, '<', "fileB" ) or die $!; 
while ( <$file2> ) {
   print if m/$search_regex/;
}
close ( $file2 );
```

If you want to ensure you don't have blank lines:

```
my $search_regex = join ( "|", grep { m/^\w+$/ } map {quotemeta} @search_for ); 
   $search_regex = qr/$search_regex/;
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have edited my input examples and so they have matching terms. But problem is that all the lines from fileB are printed as output, not only those which has matching strings with file A

Comment: It worked. Actually there was a blank line in fileA so it was printing everything. Many Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

The following command worked

grep -w -F -f fileA fileB > fileC

Initially it did not work because there was a blank line in fileA, that's why it was printing everything from fileB. Now I removed blank line from fileA and got my required lines.